# `pip` failed to install package inside Docker container due to 'Move Permanently' error returned from `https://pypi.python.org/simple/`

Tags: python-2.7, docker, pip, ubuntu-14.04, pypi

I would like to install `pip` packages inside a `Ubuntu 14.04` `docker` container but it always shows errors due to `Move Permanently` returned from `https://pypi.python.org/simple/`. The weird (?) point is that the host running `Ubuntu 14.04` and the same versions of `python` & `pip` was successful to install `pip` packages.

Docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.6-cs13, build 0ee24d4
```

Dockerfile: (**Note**: For testing I intentionally enter inside the container).

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq install python python-pip
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

On host:

```
$ uname -a
Linux duong2179-ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ sudo pip install simplejson==3.3.1
Downloading/unpacking simplejson==3.3.1
...
Successfully installed simplejson
```

Inside container:

```
# uname -a
Linux duong2179-ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# python --version
Python 2.7.6
# pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
# pip install simplejson==3.3.1
Downloading/unpacking simplejson==3.3.1
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement simplejson==3.3.1
```

From host do `curl`-ing `https://pypi.python.org/simple/`:

```
$ curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/
<html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center></body></html>
```

Comment: Naive question (for I am not very familiar with Docker): can you access Internet from inside of your container? Can you do a **curl** or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem of `pip 1.5.4`

Add following line to your `Dockerfile` before using `pip`:

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```